# Cannot commit StringSet to SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I using the following code to create a set of strings, but everytime I call commit, it always returns false and never saves, and instead gives this error:

```
Couldn't create directory for SharedPreferences file /data/user/0/com.identifier.my/shared_prefs/MyApp.xml
```

I am creating a new hash set every time. I am never modifying the returned stringSet in place, only iterating over it in another method. I have tried using `editor.apply()` and have tried saving in a while loop until `commit()` returns true, which it never does.

```
    HashSet<String> params = new HashSet<>();
    for (String strs : myExisitingStrings) {
        params.add(strs);
    }
    SharedPreferences prefs =_context.getSharedPreferences("MyApp",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.remove("params"); //have tried with this line removed as well
    editor.putStringSet("params",params);
    boolean saved = editor.commit();
```

Comment: I copied your code into an activity in a fresh project and it ran fine (saved = true). Are you running this on an emulator or a real device? From what context (an activity, a service, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was using the wrong context. My apk runs as a plugin in another app, apparently only the app's context can be used, not the plugins.